# Why is this multiple file input in jquery validate not showing any error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate a multiple file input. I have rules for it. However the very basic thing of required: true is not working. Here is my code..

```
        <form id="profile-form" action="" method="post">

            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label style="padding-left:20px;padding-top:10px">Upload image<strong> (5 images required)<strong></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" id="files" accept="png|jpg|jpeg" required="required" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The validation.js containing the rules are as follows:

```
     $("#profile-form").validate({
    rules: {

      name: {
        required: true,
        nowhitespace: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },

 'files[]': {
            required: true,
          },    
    },

    messages: {

      name: {
        required: 'Please enter your first name',
      },
      'files[]': {
        required: 'Please insert your 5 images',
      },
      }
});
```

Comment: what validator are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery validate library

Comment: It is working for all other validations. All the 40 validations that I have written in same manner; they work and this one doesnt show the custom error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `required` attribute

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" id="files" accept="png|jpg|jpeg" required="required" multiple>
```

or:

```
rules:{
    'files[]': {
            required: true,
          },
},
message:{
    'files[]': {
            required: 'Please insert your 5 images',
          },
}
```

Note: you will need to create a new rule to count the 5 images

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with this:

```
files[]: {
        required: true
      },

files[]: {
        required: 'Please insert your 5 images'
      },
```

Also, add

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" id="files" accept="png|jpg|jpeg" required="required" multiple>
```

Comment: I tried this code. Same result. It prints its custom message.. ie. This field is required

Comment: I have written same thing. Still it shows same result( This field is required).

Answer (score 0):

You can also add simple function as following:
message: {
        required: "This field is required."
    }